# Using xargs to copy text into an array of files

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to copy the output of a file into multiple files using echo, xargs and cp. My problem is xargs is only printing to the first file in my array instead of printing a copy to all 3 files. Am I using xargs incorrectly or is my syntax incorrect. I've been working on this for a couple of days and multiple Google pages with no luck so far. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#!/bin/bash

NF1=/home/user3/mynewfile
U3=/home/user3/
File=(grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2)

mkdir -p /home/user3/{CIT/{tests/,grades/},MyStuff/{Tests/,Labs/},NOS/};
echo /etc/hosts.allow > $NF1;
echo $U3/CIT/tests/${File[*]} $U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]} | xargs -n 1 cp $NF1
```

Comment: (1) Don’t go from taking a walk in the park to climbing Mt. Everest; simplify.  Your nested braces expression (`{…{…,…},…{…,…},…}`) may be working correctly, but it makes your question unreadable.  Don’t use five-level pathnames unless they are essential to the question.  Don’t have multiple files with the same name (`/home/user3/mynewfile` and `/home/user3/CIT/tests/mynewfile`, `/home/user3/CIT/grades` and `/home/user3/CIT/tests/grades`).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Don’t show us the commands that you use to create your input files (`echo /etc/hosts.allow > $NF1`) unless they are central to the question.  Arbitrarily and unnecessarily creating files that contain filenames is confusing.  (2) Please try to use clear terminology.  What is “the output of a file”?  If you mean “the output of a command”, say so.  If you mean “copy the content of a file”, say that, or just “copy a file”.  (3) You should always quote shell variables (e.g., `"$NF1"` and `"$U3"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected it has something to do syntax, but I also found some other issues, and came up with a version that just dropped the use of `xargs` altogether in favor a `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

U3=/home/user3/
NF1=/home/user3/mynewfile
File=(grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2)

mkdir -p /home/user3/{CIT/{tests,grades},MyStuff/{Tests,Labs},NOS};

echo /etc/hosts.allow > $NF1;

for i in "${File[@]}"; do
    cp $NF1 $U3/$i
done

cp $NF1 $U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]}
```

- `mkdir` line was simplified to drop the unnecessary trailing slashes, `mkdir` still makes directories with trailing slash or not, so no need for more typing

The reasons for the rest of the changes:

### Redundant Slash

Firstly, when testing a few lines of the original code:

```
$ U3=/home/user3/
$ File=(grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2)
$ echo $U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]}
/home/user3//CIT/grades/mynewfile1
```

The path saved to `$U3` was set with a trailing slash, then the line  `$U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]}` also has a slash after `$U3` thus causing bash to expand it to `/home/user3//CIT/grades/mynewfile1` , this is a problem because double slash `//` is not the same as `/`, `cp` for example may complain `no such file or directory`.

So if you meant single slash `/`, the recommended method is to just set `$U3` to have no trailing slash in the first place:

```
$ U3=/home/user3
$ File=(grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2)
$ echo $U3/CIT/tests/${File[2]}
/home/user3/CIT/tests/mynewfile1
```

So it now results in a proper path, no redundant slashes.

### Incorrect Brace Expansion

With that corrected, the next bug was:

```
$ echo $U3/CIT/tests/${File[*]}
/home/user3/CIT/tests/grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2
```

I'm guessing you had intended to expand the file names in the `File` array, using `/home/user3/CIT/tests` as a common prefix, sort of like this brace expansion with commas:

```
$ echo tweedle{dum,dee}
tweedledum tweedledee
```

In this form of brace expansion

- a string is right adjacent to the brace `{` either before or after `}` or both, which you've correctly done
- but a `word` , comma `,` another word is used, etc
- however you put a `${File[*]}`, I haven't yet seen it work with array contents in this manner

Instead, to output a list made from combining the same common starting word or string (`$U3`) plus another part that is different based on an array (`$File`), I recommend a `for` loop:

```
$ for i in "${File[@]}"; do
> echo $U3/$i
> done
```

Note that you don't type `>` , bash automatically supplied that to indicate line continuation. In a script you just have:

```
for i in "${File[@]}"; do
    echo $U3/$i
done
```

The result is always

```
/home/user3/grades
/home/user3/mynewfile
/home/user3/mynewfile1
/home/user3/mynewfile2
```

- in `for i in "${File[@]}"; do` , the quote (`"`), plus `@` is important to have the `for` loop properly understanding each filename in `$File` array as separate arguments.

### Test

Ultimately the goal is to copy a single file, referenced by variable `$NF1`, to multiple places, defined by both the expansion of `$U3` plus `$File` array plus `$U3/CIT/tests/${File[2]}`

Best practice to do a test with echo and the command you intend to do, in this case `cp`, so you can see what will be run unless you want to use `set`. So first for our test, :

```
$ NF1=/home/user3/mynewfile
```

Then

```
$ for i in "${File[@]}"; do
> echo cp $NF1 $U3/$i
> done
cp /home/user3/mynewfile /home/user3/grades
cp /home/user3/mynewfile /home/user3/mynewfile
cp /home/user3/mynewfile /home/user3/mynewfile1
cp /home/user3/mynewfile /home/user3/mynewfile2
```

Also it seems you wanted to copy to `$U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]}` so we don't forget it, but add it as an additional line:

```
$ echo cp $NF1 $U3/CIT/grades/${File[2]}
cp /home/user3/mynewfile /home/user3/CIT/grades/mynewfile1
```

- it all echoes the `cp` commands that would be run
- it could be re-written to direct the arguments to use `xargs` similar to your original code but that actually involves more typing so we avoid it

So, simply remove the `echo` in this text example to create the final version of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is going wrong with the script as written; using `set -x` as the second line of the script is a good start for debugging, as don_crissti pointed out.  I don't know xargs and array expansion well enough to see at a glance what is wrong.

*However*, there is an easy workaround, and it's probably **a better way to solve this problem** anyway: just use `tee`.  It allows you to write to multiple files in one command, and it even allows for appending text instead of replacing file contents (if that's what you want).

If I'm reading your script right, what you want would look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

NF1=/home/user3/mynewfile
U3=/home/user3/
File=(grades mynewfile mynewfile1 mynewfile2)

mkdir -p /home/user3/{CIT/{tests/,grades/},MyStuff/{Tests/,Labs/},NOS/};
cd ${U3}CIT/tests/
echo /etc/hosts.allow | tee ${File[*]} ${U3}CIT/grades/${File[2]} $NF1
cd -
```

EDIT: Array expansion uses space separation by default; therefore I added a `cd` so the files "mynewfile, mynewfile1, mynewfile2" will be created in /home/user3/CIT/tests instead of in the current working directory.  (There are undoubtedly cleaner ways to do this.)

Comment: Actually, are you trying to insert the CONTENTS of /etc/hosts.allow into all of these files?  If so, use `cat` instead of `echo`.

Comment: @Linux: See, this is exactly what I was referring to when I said "Arbitrarily and unnecessarily creating files that contain filenames is confusing.".

Comment: @G-Man, of course you're right.  I think the mind-boggling complexity of this 5-line script to accomplish so little means there is definitely something wrong with the plan for the script in the first place.  (Like, the entire script is probably completely unnecessary and is probably solving a problem that's already solved in basic Linux tools.)  However, I wasn't doing a code review; just tweaking the snippet I was presented with so that it would work as the author intended.  ;)

Comment: Um, I hope you notice the formatting issues with your comment...anyway, if all you want to do is create that directory tree, there are a LOT simpler ways to go about it.  The real question here is, why are you *scripting* this?  Obviously you've had ample time to create that directory tree *once*.  Why do you need it in a script?  Are you going to do this on multiple computers?  If so, why not make the script *readable* by using an explicit `mkdir -p` command for each full directory path, and then use a `touch` command for each file?  It will be more code, but more readable.

Comment: (Cont) Unless this is a purely academic exercise of how to use the fewest characters possible to create that directory tree, readability is more important than saving a few bytes of space.  Also it's very unclear if the actual desired behavior is to (a) create empty files in the specified locations (b) append to existing files if present (c) overwrite existing files if present or (d) copy one file to multiple locations.  These would all have different approaches.  Don't tie yourself in knots trying to reduce the amount of code present, just get it working.  It's scripting, not CS 101.

Comment: @Wildcard sorry for the illegible formatting, that was a complete mistake on my part. You are correct I will be using this script on multiple machines multiple times a year, and it was purely an academic exercise for my own knowledge. I wanted to create a directory structure in as few characters as possible. The script would be run on a fresh install every semester for about 30 virtual machines, and I just wanted to copy the contents of the hosts.allow file into a few files that were in different directories. I would like to thank everyone for their advice I am learning as I go for sure!

Comment: @LinuxCare, if it is rapid virtual machine setup you are looking for, I highly recommend checking out Vagrant (in conjunction with VirtualBox).  For general Linux basics and overall rounding out, nothing I've seen beats LFS101, which is the free online Linux basics course.  (I used edx.org as my platform for study; search LFS101 there and you'll see it.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice I will defiantly check out Vagrant as I see they have incorporated KVM now. What I have is a Centos host machine and I spin up about 30 machines for my students every semester using KVM. I have my RHCSA (Testing for my RHCE in December) but am lacking a lot of knowledge in scripting and would really like to improve in that area. Once again thanks for sharing your knowledge.